# Unable to use prop availability to toggle gradient input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have the following component which currently only shows gradient if the gradientProps is passed in

when calling it. This works as intended.

```
    backgroundImage: `url('${imageUrl}') ${
        $gradientProps
            ? `, linear-gradient(${
                $gradientProps.angle
            }, ${$gradientProps.colors.join()})`
            : ""
    }`
```

But finding it bit cumbersome to have to pass in an empty string when gradientProps is not passed in.

Alternatively looking to use && instead as follows which feels cleaner as follows.

```
    backgroundImage: `url('${imageUrl}') ${$gradientProps &&
      `, linear-gradient(${
        $gradientProps.angle
      }, ${$gradientProps.colors.join()})`}`,
```

But taking this route, everything works only if I pass in the gradientProps.
Else I end up with a white background.

Could I get some advice as to what I am doing wrong pls? Thanks.

My Component

```
import React from "react";

interface GradientProps {
    angle: string;
    colors: string[];
}

interface Props {
    imageUrl: string;
    children?: React.ReactNode;
    $gradientProps?: GradientProps;
}

const MyComponent = ({
 imageUrl,
 children,
 $gradientProps
}: Props): React.ReactElement => {
    return (
        <div
            style={{
                backgroundImage: `url('${imageUrl}') ${$gradientProps &&
                `, linear-gradient(${
                    $gradientProps.angle
                }, ${$gradientProps.colors.join()})`}`,
            }}
        >
            {children && (<div>{children}</div>)}
        </div>
    );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

Calling the component as follows:

```
// works fine 
<MyComponent
  imageUrl="/a.svg"
  $gradientProps={{
    angle: '20deg',
    colors: ['red', 'blue'],
  }}
/>

//end up with white background cos not passing in the gradientProps. 
<MyComponent
  imageUrl="/a.svg"
/>
```